# Why is my shape not filling when i extend vertices?

Tags: edit-mode

Image:
[image]

3rd Day learning blender, trying to use this reference image to make a sword, but realized after all my time that when i extend the vertices the shape isn't filling within the vertices? Why? and is there a better way of doing this that i'm unaware of?

Comment: just select vertices, press F and it will be magically be filled ;) i would suggest watching some beginner modeller tutorials - e.g. from Blender itself - they are a really good starting point

Comment: if you extrude an edge (2 or more adjacent vertices) it should create a face. Maybe share your file?